# How to logout automatically when session expires while using createAsyncThunk and axios (withcredential) option using react and redux toolkit?

Tags: reactjs, axios, redux-thunk, redux-toolkit

I am trying to logout the user when the session expires after a certain period of time. I am using `redux-toolkit` with `react` for my API calls and, hence, using the `createAsyncThunk` **middleware** for doing so.

I have around 60 API calls made in maybe 20 `slices` throughout my application. Also, there is a async function for logout too that is fired up on the button click. Now the problem that I am facing is that if the session expires, I am not able to logout the user automatically. If I had to give him the message, then I had to take up that message from every api call and make sure that every screen of mine has a logic to notify the **Unautherised** message.

I did check a method called ***Polling*** that calls an API after a certain given time. And I believe that this is not a very efficient way to handle this problem.

**Here is a little code that will help you understand how my API calls are being made in the slices of my application. **

```
// Here is the custom created api that has axios and withcredentials value

import axios from "axios";

const api = axios.create({
  baseURL:
    process.env.NODE_ENV === "development" ? process.env.REACT_APP_BASEURL : "",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
  withCredentials: true,
});

export default api;


// My Logout Function!!


export const logoutUser = createAsyncThunk(
  "userSlice/logoutUser",
  async (thunkAPI) => {
    try {
      const response = await api.get("/api/admin/logout");
      if (response.status === 200) {
        return response.data;
      } else {
        return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(response.data);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(e.response.data);
    }
  }
);
```

I want to dispatch this function whenever there is a response `status-code` is `401 - Unauthorised`. But I don't want to keep redundant code for all my other API calls calling this function. If there is a middleware that might help handle this, that would be great, or any solution will be fine.

```
// Rest of the APIs are called in this way.

..........

export const getStatus = createAsyncThunk(
  "orgStat/getStatus",
  async (thunkAPI) => {
    try {
      const response = await api.get("/api/admin/orgstat");
      if (response.status === 200) {
        return response.data;
      } else {
        return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(response.data);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(e.response.data);
    }
  }
);

const OrgStatusSlice = createSlice({
  name: "orgStat",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    .......
  },
  extraReducers: {
    [getStatus.pending]: (state) => {
      state.isFetching = true;
    },
    [getStatus.rejected]: (state, { payload }) => {
      state.isFetching = false;
      state.isError = true;
      state.isMessage = payload.message;
    },
    [getStatus.fulfilled]: (state, { payload }) => {
      state.isFetching = false;
      state.data = payload.data;
    },
  },
});

.......
```

If needed any more clearence please comment I will edit the post with the same.

**Thank You!!**

Comment: It can be handled effecienly using axios interceptos. endpoint should throw a status code in case of session expired. So you can catch it in interceptor and perform store disptach action.

Comment: Do you have any code references that I can refer to? That would be a great help!!
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

import axios from 'axios'
import errorParser from '../services/errorParser'
import toast from 'react-hot-toast'
import {BaseQueryFn} from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query'
import {baseQueryType} from './apiService/types/types'
import store from './store'
import {handleAuth} from './common/commonSlice'
import storageService from '@services/storageService'

// let controller = new AbortController()
export const axiosBaseQuery =
(
{baseUrl}: {baseUrl: string} = {baseUrl: ''}
): BaseQueryFn<baseQueryType, unknown, unknown> =>
async ({url, method, data, csrf, params}) => {
const API = axios.create({
baseURL: baseUrl,
})

```
    API.interceptors.response.use(
        (res) => {
            if (
                res.data?.responseCode === 1023 ||
                res.data?.responseCode === 6023
            ) {
                if(res.data?.responseCode === 1023){

                    console.log('session expired')
                    store.dispatch(handleSession(false))
                    return
                }
                console.log('Lopgged in somewhere else')
                store.dispatch(handleSession(false))
                
                storageService.clearStorage()
                // store.dispatch(baseSliceWithTags.util.resetApiState())
                return
                // }, 1000)
            }
            return res
        },
        (error) => {
            const expectedError =
                error.response?.status >= 400 &&
                error.response?.status < 500
            if (!expectedError) {
                if (error?.message !== 'canceled') {
                    toast.error('An unexpected error occurrred.')
                }
            }

            if (error.response?.status === 401) {
                //   Storage.clearJWTToken();
                // window.location.assign('/')
            }

            return Promise.reject(error)
        }
    )

    try {
        let headers = {}
        if (csrf) headers = {...csrf}

        const result = await API({
            url: url,
            method,
            data,
            headers,
            params: params ? params : '',
            baseURL: baseUrl,
            // signal: controller.signal,
        })
        return {data: result.data}
    } catch (axiosError) {
        const err: any = axiosError
        return {
            error: {
                status: errorParser.parseError(err.response?.status),
                data: err.response?.data,
            },
        }
    }
}
```

I am also using RTK with Axios. You can refer to the attached image.

[image]